# Display Popup Message many times in Asp .Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, popupwindow

I am working on a  asp net project I need to add some choices to popup window and whenever I selected popup window and select choices from dropdownlist click on OK button to  hidden panel and show web form Next time I click LnkBtnGet button display popup window.My problem Wheen select first time it was work ,second times  clicked LnkBtnGet seening Dropdownlist but  button  dissappear. How can solve this problem . Please Help me.

Form Code

```
<div class="tools"><asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnGet"  runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"  Text="+Add" OnClick="LnkBtnGet_Click"  />
  </div>
```

Javascript code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function BlockUI(elementID) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(function () {
        $("#" + elementID).block({
            message: '<table align = "center"><tr><td>' +
     '<img src="images/loadingAnim.gif"/></td></tr></table>',
            css: {},
            overlayCSS: {
                backgroundColor: '#000000', opacity: 0.6
            }
        });
    });
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $("#" + elementID).unblock();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    BlockUI("<%=pnlAddEdit.ClientID %>");
    $.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
});
    function Hidepopup() {
        $find("popup").hide();
        return false;
    }
```

Panel Code 1: `

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style = "display:none">
```

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" Width="180px" Height="40px" runat="server">       </asp:DropDownList>           
    <asp:Button Width="150px" Height="40px" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="OK" Visible="true" OnClick="Save"></asp:Button> </table>
```

`

Panel Code 2

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ></asp:LinkButton><cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup"runat="server" DropShadow="false"PopupControlID="pnlAddEdit"TargetControlID = "lnkFake"BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Don't put the ample of code please be clear where you are getting the problem and paste that only.

Answer (score 0):

Alter line popup to `<%=popup.ClientID %>`